# Можно ли парсить построчно из постов в тг канале?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Т.е каждую строчку поста сохранять в определённую переменную, а потом реквестнуть эту переменную в инпут на сайт?

Comment: Ответ: да, можно

Comment: Можешь, пожалуйста, подсказать как? Это в телеботе чи как?

Comment: Уточните в своём вопросе, с чем именно возникли проблемы. Сейчас он [[вопрос](https://www.google.com/search?q=граббер+постов+телеграм)] выглядит так, будто бы на google.com Вас заблокировали